# anchor link is not clickable in full width

Tags: html, css

I make a list that looks like the picture below. My problem is that not the whole link is clickable, only the text. I can't make a `display: block` on the `anchor` and give the link the full width because I already gave the `anchor` `display: table-cell`.

Here you can can see my problem and try out your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kma_999/v0xkk587/

Thanks in advance!

[image: Image of the list]

HTML:

```
<div class="pane-content">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Kostenkontrolle (Mobile)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sunrise Rechnung</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Umzug</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Telefonieren im Ausland (Roaming)</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 0px solid black; 
}

ul li a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 75px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li a:hover{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:after {
    content: "\25b6";
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: table-row;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li:last-child a {
  border-bottom-width: 0; 
}

ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 75px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can see [example](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/CaFkG)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ul li a {
    display: inline-table;
    height: 75px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    line-height:75px;
}
```

Comment: this don't work. Vertical-align:middle don't work when i change display:block to display: inline-table

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 20px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i allready said i can't change table-cell to block because i wan't to keep vertical-align: middle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul li a {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;   // changed
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;     // added
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this just work half ways. The full link is clickable that's right but when the text is too long then the rest of the text jumps to the next list item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ul li a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 75px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: black;
    width: 500px;
}
```

I replace the `width` of `a` tag `100%` to that of parent (`li`). Then it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
ul li a {       
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Instead giving it to vertical align middle you can also use line-height for make it middle.

Comment: this also just work half ways. The full link is clickable that's right but when the text is too long then the rest of the text jumps to the next list item.